# Is there a way to make the .NET Cast<T> extension method use user defined implicit cast operators?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, extension-methods

When I define an implicit cast operator, then attempt to invoke it on a whole collection of objects at once using the `Cast<T>` extension method, I get an InvalidCastException. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Why dont you just solve the problem at hand instead of trying to bypass the error

Comment: Solve the problem at hand? Because I don't know what the solution is, or even how to define the problem, apart from "the Cast<T> extension method doesn't work the way I'd expect it to"...

Comment: Well, that's fine. The duplicate I suggested will have a workaround and explanation of why it fails as well. What else you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Cast` treats each item as `Object` and casts it to the target type, so it can't use user-defined conversions because conversion are resolved statically. Instead you can just do this:

```
collection.Select(x => (YourType)x)
```

Comment: The duplicate was suggested 6 minutes before you submitted this answer :(

Answer (score 1):

No.

`Cast` is a CLR method. It does not incorporate C# specific binding rules because it is independent of any specific CLR language. Implicit conversions are specific to a few .NET languages.

You have to create your own version of `Cast`.

Comment: Put another way, `Cast<T>` has nothing to do with C#, so your C# implicit cast won't be used by it.

Comment: Am confused. *Cast is a CLR method* What do you mean by that?

Comment: So implicit operators I define in C# won't work in VB, then? E.g. if I define one to convert a Foo to a Bar, and then in VB I say Dim x As Bar = New Foo(), I'll get an error?

Comment: @ekolis I don't know what VB.NET does. It will certainly use VB rules and not C# rules.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize implicit casts were specific to C#. Does VB not have an equivalent feature?

Comment: @ekolis I don't know.